How can I get the whole folder structure/tree of an ACC-project
I need to get the full folder structure/tree of an ACC-project (to be exact of all my projects).
I'm aware of the hubs/:hub_id/projects/:project_id/topFolders and projects/:project_id/folders/:folder_id/contents endpoints, but in my case building up the folder structure recursively like this is not really an option (building up the whole tree accross multiple projects would result in several millions of request in my case).
I'm familiar with the projects/:project_id/folders/:folder_id/searchtext endpoint, but this one only returns files and no folders.
Does anyone know a workaround/solution for that?
